# Carbon now wrong date after store in variable laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I got wrong date after I put it on $order->start_date,
somehow it changed the date to 2018-3-16

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); //2018-3-17 ...
$order->start_date = $today;
dd($order->start_date); //2018-3-16 ...
```

But If I do this, I got the correct date

```
$order->start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
dd($order->start_date); //2018-3-17 ...
```

Can Someone advise whats wrong here? why it got changed if I put it on $today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `toDateTimeString` to your carbon Date format:

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(); //2018-3-17 ...
$order->start_date = $today
```